# Make user download latest version of iPhone app

Tags: ios, app-store

I already have an app in appstore with Version 1.0.0. 
I found few issue after submitting the app.

Now that I have released version 1.0.1, is there a way to tell apple or make new user download version 1.0.1 instead of having user to download version 1.0.0 and update it to 1.0.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK here's the deal:

Ones your app status is changed to "Ready for Sale" it is instantly available for upgrade in appstore. However for the users who will be installing your app for the first time they would still get the older version to download. They will have to update the newer version from appstore.

This drama can go on anywhere between 24-48 hours since you app status has changed to "Ready for Sale". After 48 hours new users should be able to download the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

The users will be informed that an update is available, but you can't force them to upgrade without implementing that feature in code.

Comment: What happens in case of NEW USER?

Comment: They will download the lastest available version, as stated in my answer. Go try it yourself and download Apps like Shazam and see what version you get.

Answer (score 0):

That is done automatically, if Apple accepts your version 1.0.1. However, I don't really see any "value" in this question, as it'd pretty specific and has no real relation to programming itself.

Comment: Even I thought that it should update the app automatically. But when I delete the app on my phone and download it from the app store I get the old version (1.0.0)

Comment: As said before, Apple needs to approve version 1.0.1 before releasing it to the AppStore

Comment: Could you tell me the name of the Application? Also, it might take up to 24 hours to get it released.

Comment: It's not available on the Austrian appstore, but on the U.S. store, it still shows 1.0.0, so please be patient.

Comment: Yes its only targeted for specific location. Usually how long is the wait time?

Comment: 24 hours, as stated 6 times approximately.

Comment: Since it already shows the latest version in app store, I got confused

Answer (score 0):

Once your update is approved and in the store, new users will only see the new version. Existing users will be told, through the App Store app, that there is an update but nothing forces an update.

If you want to prevent users from using an old version once a new version is available, you will need to add code to your app that checks with your own server. If it is told there is an update, you can display an alert that there is a new version and prevent the user from using the app until they upgrade.

Comment: Even I thought that it should update the app automatically. But when I delete the app on my phone and download it from the app store I get the old version (1.0.0). I there some kind of caching happening on the phone?

Comment: When you delete the app and use the App Store app, what version of your app is shown? Keep in mind that is can take up to 24 hours after you are told the app is ready for the store before the update appears for everyone.

Comment: It shows the older version. But in the app store I see the new update.

Comment: @HarisFarooqui What shows the older version and what shows the new version? How long ago did you get the email from Apple stating that the app was ready for the app store (not processing, but actually ready)?

Comment: Its been more than 4 hours since I got the mail which says "Ready for sale". In the app store I see the latest version but it downloads the older version.

Comment: Please actually read the comments! It takes up to 24 hours to be actually available.

Comment: @HarisFarooqui As you've been told by me and others in various answers and comments, it can take up to 24 hours for updates to appear. If you still have this problem this time tomorrow, then start to worry.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way !

If you have a server you can always do the following

- At the beginning of your app, run a HTTP request to your server
- Send in the request the version of the current app (let's say 1.0.0)
- On the server side, check for the app version (transform it into 100 and hard code the lastest version of your app on the server than compare) - Oh God ! 100 < 101 ! This app needs a serious update =P
- Send back (in JSON or whatever) to the iPhone a message like { message : "lastest_version" } or { message : "need_update" }. In your case it's a fail message.
- Check on the phone side if what you received from the server is a go or not
- Then continue if everything is fine or tell the user he needs to update (or can still continue but with a bugged experience)